# How to convert XML to JSON in node.js without having first two elements from xml file?

Tags: json, node.js, xml, mongodb

I would like to know I can I parse XML to JSON without having the two first elements from the first xml conversion, but rather a result like the second convertion. xml2js gives me the first conversion.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
          of the world.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

When I convert it with xml2json, I get this output :

```
`{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "-id": "bk101",
        "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
        "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "44.95",
        "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
        "description": "An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML."
      },
      {
        "-id": "bk102",
        "author": "Ralls, Kim",
        "title": "Midnight Rain",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95",
        "publish_date": "2000-12-16",
        "description": "A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world."
      }
    ]
  }
}`
```

But i would want this output:

```
`[
   {
      "@id": "bk101",
      "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
      "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
      "genre": "Computer",
      "price": "44.95",
      "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
      "description": "An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML."
   },
   {
      "@id": "bk102",
      "author": "Ralls, Kim",
      "title": "Midnight Rain",
      "genre": "Fantasy",
      "price": "5.95",
      "publish_date": "2000-12-16",
      "description": "A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world."
   }
]`
```

The reason is I need this to insert in my mongodb, but the first conversion only puts all the json as one entry in my database. Also, I have a csv insertion (that I also converted in JSON) that matches the second format and was inserted correctly in the database. Is there a way to get the 2nd format instead of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert your XML to JS object and do manipulations with it, removing unnecessary data.

Example

```
const obj = xml2json.toJson(xml, { object: true });
const books = obj.catalog.book;
// here you have an array of JS objects stored in your variable books
// and you can perform operations

// just an example for mongo insertion
const collection = db.collection('books');
collection.insertMany(books).then(function () {
    console.log('books inserted')
})
```

Full set of options for parser can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)

Comment: Yeah, it was just a matter of manipulating the object after getting the conversion. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
const xml = ` <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
     <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
     <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
     <genre>Computer</genre>
     <price>44.95</price>
     <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
     <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
     with XML.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
     <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
     <title>Midnight Rain</title>
     <genre>Fantasy</genre>
     <price>5.95</price>
     <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
     <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
     an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
     of the world.</description>
  </book>
</catalog>`

const { parseString } = require('xml2js')
const opts = {
    mergeAttrs: true,
    attrNameProcessors: [str => '@' + str],
}

parseString(xml, opts, (err, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
})
```

Result:

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "@id": "bk101",
        "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
        "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "44.95",
        "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
        "description": "An in-depth look at creating applications \n     with XML."
      },
      {
        "@id": "bk102",
        "author": "Ralls, Kim",
        "title": "Midnight Rain",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95",
        "publish_date": "2000-12-16",
        "description": "A former architect battles corporate zombies, \n     an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen \n     of the world."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: shameless plug:

[Cruftless](https://github.com/wspringer/cruftless) is *almost* able to do it — but not entirely. Cruftless aims to be a library that allows you to have a single definition of the structure of an XML file, and then use that to both parse data from a document or produce an XML document from the data. As a consequence, it works a bit different than all of the examples above:

```
const xml = …
const template = parse(`<catalog>
  <book id="{{id}}" c-bind="books|array">
    <author>{{author}}</author>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <genre>{{genre}}</genre>
    <price>{{price}}</price>
    <publish_date>{{publicationDate}}</publish_date>
    <description>{{desc}}</description>
  </book>
</catalog>`)
template.fromXML(xml)
```

produces:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "bk101",
      "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
      "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
      "genre": "Computer",
      "price": "44.95",
      "publicationDate": "2000-10-01",
      "desc": "An in-depth look at creating applications \n      with XML."
    },
    {
      "id": "bk102",
      "author": "Ralls, Kim",
      "title": "Midnight Rain",
      "genre": "Fantasy",
      "price": "5.95",
      "publicationDate": "2000-12-16",
      "desc": "A former architect battles corporate zombies, \n      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen \n      of the world."
    }
  ]
}
```